# Is there a way to overlap a time series data table onto another using an sql query?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, time-series

hoping I can find an answer to my conundrum here.

I have two tables in a Postgres DB and I'd like to overlap on onto the other.

Table A has 3 columns: "start time", "end time" and "state". In each row, the start time is equal to the end time of the preceding row.

Table B has has the same columns but the start & end times aren't adjacent and they do not overlap.

I want to overlap Table B onto Table A to create Table C.

Table C also has the start time of each row equal to the end time of the preceding row.

Here is an example to clarify:

**Table A** *- Overlapee*

| State | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12:00:00 AM | 12:10:00 AM |
| 2 | 12:10:00 AM | 12:20:00 AM |
| 1 | 12:20:00 AM | 12:30:00 AM |
| 2 | 12:30:00 AM | 12:40:00 AM |
| 1 | 12:40:00 AM | 12:50:00 AM |
| 2 | 12:50:00 AM | 1:00:00 AM |

**Table B** *- Overlaper*

| State | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 12:05:00 AM | 12:25:00 AM |
| 6 | 12:31:00 AM | 12:35:00 AM |
| 5 | 12:40:00 AM | 12:50:00 AM |

**Table C** *- Result of overlap*

| State | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12:00:00 AM | 12:05:00 AM |
| 5 | 12:05:00 AM | 12:25:00 AM |
| 1 | 12:25:00 AM | 12:30:00 AM |
| 2 | 12:30:00 AM | 12:31:00 AM |
| 6 | 12:31:00 AM | 12:35:00 AM |
| 2 | 12:35:00 AM | 12:40:00 AM |
| 5 | 12:40:00 AM | 12:50:00 AM |
| 2 | 12:50:00 AM | 1:00:00 AM |

As you can see, if the start time of a row in table B falls within a rows time range in table A , then the end time of the row in table A is replaced with the start time of the row in table B. Conversely, if the end time of a row in table B falls within a time range in table A, then the start time of the row in table A is replaced with the end time of the row in table B.

Secondly, If the start time and end time in Table A and B are exactly the same, then the row in B simply replaces that in A.

Thirdly, If the time range for a row in Table B falls within a time range for a row in Table A, then the Table A row is split into 2, with the end time of the first row being the start time of the Table B row and then start time of the second row would be the end time of the Table B row.

Lastly, the state must be preserved for the time range correctly.

Is it possible to accomplish this with a **postgres** sql query?. I haven't found any similar questions or answers.

**Note:** There is also an ID column in each table that I left off here for simplicity but can be used if it will help achieve the overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to extract all the start times and end times, then pull the correct state at that start time, and use `lead()` to get the end time:

```
with t as (
      select starttime as tm
      from a
      union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      select endtime
      from a
      union 
      select starttime as tm
      from b
      union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      select endtime
      from b
     )
select t.tm, lead(t.tm) over (order by t.tm) as endtime,
       (select ab.state
        from ((select a.*
               from a
              ) union all
              (select b.*
               from b
              )
             ) ab
        where ab.starttime <= t.tm and t.tm < ab.endtime
        order by ab.starttime desc
        limit 1
       ) as state
from t;
```